# Limit of a non negative sequence $a_n \leq \frac{a_{n-1} + 2 a_{n-2}}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I tried to upper bound $a_n$ by some formula involving $a_0$ and $a_1$.

I have the following:

$a_2 \leq \frac{1}{4}a_1 + \frac{1}{2}a_0$

$a_3 \leq \frac{9}{16}a_1 + \frac{1}{8}a_0$

$a_4 \leq \frac{17}{64}a_1 + \frac{9}{32}a_0$

$a_5 \leq \frac{89}{256}a_1 + \frac{17}{128}a_0$

$a_6 \leq \frac{225}{1024}a_1 + \frac{89}{512}a_0$

$a_7 \leq \frac{937}{4096}a_1 + \frac{225}{2048}a_0$

This implies $a_n \leq \frac{??}{4^{n-1}}a_1 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{??}{4^{n-2}}a_0$.

Does the sequence 1, 9, 17, 89, 225, 937, ... be put into a formula?

Comment: These are the generalized Fibonacci numbers with the recurrence relation $$b_n=b_{n-1}+8b_{n-2}$$ with $b_1=1$ and $b_2=9$ and the general formula for this recurrence relation is $$b_n=\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{33}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{33}}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{33}}$$

Comment: Is this a sequence of positive numbers?

Comment: @RohanShinde I'd suggest you make this an answer

Comment: yes, non negative sequence.

Comment: Still given the recurrence relation, what is the best way to find the limit?

Comment: By the way, when you have a sequence of numbers and you want to find a generator the lazy way is to use the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A015443)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best is for you to solve the original recurrence directly. It is clear that the upper bound is attained when the inequality becomes equality:
$$4a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$$
The characteristic equation of the recurrence is therefore $4t^2-t-2=0$, which has the solutions:
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{8}$$
The general solution for the upper bound is:
$$a_n=C_1\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{33}}{8}\right)^n+C_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{33}}{8}\right)^n$$
Furthermore, $C_1$ and $C_2$ can be found by equating with the first two terms:
$C_1+C_2=a_0$, and $C_1\frac{1+\sqrt{33}}{8}+C_2\frac{1-\sqrt{33}}{8}=a_1$

In any case you might see that $-1<t_{1,2}<1$, so your limit is zero.

Answer (score 2):

This technique wasn’t as easy as I originally thought it was going to be, but you could use $a_n \leq \frac{3}{4} \max ( a_{n-1}, a_{n-2} )$ to show that:

Case 1:

If $\max ( a_{n-1}, a_{n-2} ) = a_{n-1}$, then $a_n \leq \frac{3}{4} a_{n-1}$, so $\max ( a_{n}, a_{n-1} ) = a_{n-1}$, therefore $a_{n+1} \leq \frac{3}{4} a_{n-1} = \frac{3}{4} \max ( a_{n-1}, a_{n-2} )$.

Case 2:

If $\max ( a_{n-1}, a_{n-2} ) = a_{n-2}$, then $a_n \leq \frac{3}{4} a_{n-2}$. If $a_n \geq a_{n-1}$, then $\max ( a_{n}, a_{n-1} ) = a_{n}$, so $a_{n+1} \leq  \frac{3}{4} a_n \leq \frac{3}{4} a_{n-2}$. If $a_n < a_{n-1}$, then $\max ( a_{n}, a_{n-1} ) = a_{n-1}$, so $a_{n+1} \leq  \frac{3}{4} a_{n-1} \leq  \frac{3}{4} a_{n-2}$.

In either case,

$\max \left( a_{n+1}, a_n \right) \leq  \frac{3}{4} \max \left( a_{n-1}, a_{n-2} \right)$, so

$\max \left( a_{2n+2}, a_{2n+1} \right) \leq \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \max \left( a_2, a_1 \right)$.

Hence the limit is zero.